# Overriding underscore.js defaults when used with require.js as an AMD module

Tags: javascript, underscore.js, requirejs

Since underscore is loaded in as an AMD module does anyone have an recommendations on how best to set global options against underscore so that I can still access it under the same unified module name and have my overrides available.

I've played around with it and so far I basically have a wrapper in which I include underscore as a dependancy, make my modifications and then return the modified underscore.

```
paths: {
    'underscore': 'libs/underscore/1.2.3/underscore',
    'underscore-override': 'libs/underscore/define'
}
```

Inside define.js I basically have the following:

```
define(['underscore'], function (_) {

    // use mustache syntax
    _.templateSettings = {
        interpolate : /\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g
    };

    return _;

});
```

This approach works but I'm sure there is a much more elegant way to achieve this so that I don't have to use 'underscore-custom'.

Any suggestions?

Cheers :-)

***UPDATE: Based on the suggestions in the accepted answer I now do the following:***

libs/bootstrap.js

```
define([
    // add custom library defines here
    '../libs/underscore/define'
], function () {

    var libs = [].slice.call(arguments),
        initialize = function () {
            libs.forEach(function (lib) {
                if (typeof lib === 'function') {
                    lib();
                }
            });
        }

    return {
        initialize : initialize
    }

});
```

libs/underscore/define

```
define(['underscore'], function(_) {
    return function () {    
        // add custom settings here
    };
});
```

main.js

```
require(['libs'], function(libs){
    libs.initialize();
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could possibly have a configurator module that loads in anything that needs to be configured.

```
define(['underscore', 'jquery'], function(_, jQuery){
  var setUp = function(){
  // Underscore Configuration
  _.templateSettings = {};

  // jQuery Configuration
  $.someplugin = {};
  };
  return { setUp: setUp }; // or something like that
});

//main.js
define(['configurator'], function(config){
  config.setUp();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I had considered something similar to this but I wanted to keep underscore and/or jQuery specific options localised to their respective self contained defines.

However this approach could provide scope for future configuration variations.

Comment: So looks like I messed up the above, what I was trying to say was:

So I ran with this but tweaked it to support self contained library settings.

I basically now have a bootstrap include for my libraries which I use to register custom configurations. Each library I need to override or add options to I create a custom define and reference this in the bootstrap.

The bootstrap exposes an initialize function which I then call in my main.js.

Possibly over abstracted but seems to work so far. Thanks for the tip.